# Jetty: Clean up temp (work) folder only if a war in webapp folder is changed

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

I have a web application having multiple wars deployed under jetty 9.3. Before starting up jetty (using `start.jar`), I copy my wars under `${jetty.base}\webapps` folder. During startup, these wars would be extracted under `${jetty.base}\work` folder.

I don't want to cleanup `work` folder on every startup because it's huge. I want to clean it up only when any of the wars in `${jetty.base}\webapps` is changed (i.e when at least one file is changed in war or the timestamp of war is changed). Is it possible to achieve this using some flag in Jetty? It would be great if I can do it at individual war level instead of detecting a change in entire `webapps` folder.

Comment: If the `${jetty.base}/webapps/*.war` is changed then the work directory isn't reused on redeployment.   There's no need to clean it up.  Why are you thinking this is an issue that needs to be resolved?

Comment: You are right in most of the cases. Usually, work folder reflects all the latest changes in the war. However on some of my machines, there are still some old files/extra files present in `work` folder which are not in sync with war. That's why I would want to cleanup `work` folder (specifically temp extraction directory of given war) as soon as war is changes in `webapps` folder.

Comment: Are you using webapp overlays? or setting the persistTempDirectory option in your WebAppContext? or using Windows?

Comment: I am using Windows. Also persistTempDirectory options is not set.